# How to add the project folder to wix

Tags: wpf, wix, windows-installer, directory, wix3.6

How to add the project folder to wix setup so that all the references will be available 
when installed

I have created a wix setup project and it works fine 
my question is regarding the references 
when I add a new reference to the project 
how it will be available in installed folder 
I could just add it using

but my question is regarding adding the entire folder which contains all the references
so that I don't want to add it again and again..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Paraffin](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/10/21/wix-a-better-tallow-paraffin.aspx)**

You can specify which all file types, folders, etc. you want to include in the installer